# Get updated value from data attribute on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing problem with getting updated value from data attribute!

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/ZLJbt/show/

Click on (How much?) and alert will get you the current value

But after you click on (Add One More?) will add +1 to current value

If you clicked on (How much?) again will get you the old value you got before

**So how to get the updated value not the old I've gotten before?**

check the code here http://jsfiddle.net/Jim_Toth/ZLJbt/

```
$('div').click(function () {
    alert($(this).data('foo'));
});

var div = 1;
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').attr('data-foo', div);
    div += 1;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) uses `data-*` only to initialize the data values... there after if you want to modify then use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data1) sto set the value

you should set [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) not [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var div = 1;
$('button').click(function () {
    $('div').data('foo', div);
    div += 1;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/W6bfN/)

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLJbt/2/

```
$('div').click(function () {
    alert($(this).data('foo'));
});

$('button').click(function () {
    var count = $('div').data('foo') || 0;
    $('div').data('foo', count + 1) ;
});
```